# Django: Upload multiple directory of images at once

Tags: django, file-upload

In my Django project, I want to upload bulk images for products from a directory of directories. Each directory is named after SKU for a product. There may or may not be multiple images inside each directory. How can I achieve this functionality?

My Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField('SKU', max_length = 200)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length = 1000)
    price = models.CharField('Price', max_length = 200)
    quantity = models.CharField('Quantity', max_length = 200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='product_image')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Images'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('products/', views.products, name="products"),
    path('products_import/', views.products_import, name="products_import"),    
]
```

My views.py

```
def products_import(request):
    heading = 'Upload Products'
    info = '''This importer will import the following fields: sku, name, price, quantity from a csv file.'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        paramFile = io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['file'].file, encoding='latin-1')
        product = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
        list_of_dict = list(product)
        objs = [
            Product(
                sku=row['sku'],
                name=row['name'],
                price=row['price'],
                quantity=row['quantity'],
         )
         for row in list_of_dict
        ]
        record_count = len(list_of_dict)
        try:
            msg = Product.objects.bulk_create(objs)
            messages.success(request, str(record_count) + ' records were uploaded.')
            return redirect('products_import')
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = 'Error While Importing Data: ',e
            messages.error(request, error_message, e)    
            return redirect('products_import')
    context = {'heading': heading, 'info': info}
    return render(request, 'coreapp/product/products_import.html', context)
```

I can upload bulk products using the below CSV and above view.

[image]

There are multiple images inside each SKU folder below.

[image]

**I want to upload the images from the folders at once and link them with their respective SKUs.** How can I achieve that? Any guidance will be much appreciated.

NB: I can upload a single image for a product. If we want to upload thousands of products and their related images, uploading a single image is not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Copy & paste images to under MEDIA_ROOT + '/images' directory manually.

Use custom command instead of a view. It will be more useful and comfortable in that cases. Here a [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html) how to do that.

Main part of command looks like this.

```
import os
from django.conf.settings import MEDIA_ROOT


...

for data in products_data:
    product = Product.objects.create(sku=data['sku'], ...)
    images = os.listdir(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'images'))
    for image in images:
        Image.objects.create(
            product=product,
            image=f'images/{product.sku}/image'
        )
```

Be sure there is no any file except images under the images directory.